# Match float RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a float number **from 0 to 20**.

All of those must be valid:

```
1.20  
01.20  
12.00  
13,59  
11  
1  
08  
00.50
5,50
```

But **not** those:

```
001,20  
1.200  
13,
13.  
.50
```

To sum up.

- I want both *comma* and *dot* separator
- One or two digits before separator (with *minimum value = 00* and *maximum value = 20*)
- *zero, one, or two* digits after separator.

I have tried a lot of patterns but no one matches exactly.

Comment: how about writing a class to normalize the numbers first?

Comment: Use a `parseFloat` call, with simple `<=` and `>=` checks.

Comment: I use this regex for floats `/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/` it also work for numbers like `10e5`.

Comment: Make a regexp for this is a lost of time and performance. The words that @Leo and @ hjpotter92 said makes more sense.

Comment: Two questions: the separator is allowed only if there are up to 2 digits after it, right? Also, before the separator, you said 00 < X < 20, but is 20.59 allowed for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^([01]?\d)([,.]\d?\d)?$|^20([,.]0?0)?$
```

Matches everything from `0` to `20`.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/oS9lD5/2)

---

The idea is:

- `^$` - from the start til the end of the string
- `([01]?\d)` - the part before the decimal point can be a single digit number (`\d`) or have two digits, where the first is `0` or `1` (`[01]?`)
- `[,.]` - decimal point, which is either a point or a comma
- `\d?\d` - one or two digits
- `()?` - the floating part is optional
- `|` - either the above is matched, or..
- `20` - simply `20`
- `([,.]0?0)?` - with optional decimal part, which consists of decimal point with one or two *zeroes*

Comment: can u plz include 20?

Comment: @ManosSerifios, are `20.59` numbers allowed, or is only `20` the upper limit?

Comment: -1 Not because the regex is necessarily wrong, but this answer is the wrong approach to the problem. Can't beat a `parseFloat` and a less-than condition

Comment: @Matt, the question requested a regex pattern to be provided. If it was asking for a generic solution, I would have agreed with your point.

Comment: @ndn IMO, it's just as important that we guide askers to the correct solution than to assume they are chasing the right approach. Otherwise this is just a trivia site. That's just my opinion, I'll let other voters decide the rest.

Comment: @nbn is that pattern going to work with javascript reg exp system?

Comment: @ManosSerifios, yes, as you can see, the example in regex101 is in javascript mode.

Comment: @ManosSerifios, when you create regexes with `new RegExp`, you have to double escape the special characters. Use the literal syntax: `var patt20 = /^([01]?\d)([,.]\d?\d)?$|^20([,.]0?0)?$/gm;`

Comment: man thanks!! I have a huge gap of knowledge in reg exp! Soon i am gonna read more bout them but right now i dont have the time.. One last question if you want to answer me.. If i want to make the upper limit from 20 to 25 what i have to do.. If you dont have the time to answer me thats not a problem.. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @ManosSerifios, change the `([01]?\d)` to `([01]?\d|2[0-4])` and `20` to `25`.

Comment: what can i say man? U save my day! Have a happy new year man!